# Populate List with Directory

Tags: c#

I  use this

```
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pastae)) { MessageBox.Show("Must choose a folder"); }
        else
        {   nombres = Directory.GetFiles(pastae).ToArray();
            listBox1.Items.AddRange(nombres);                
        }
```

that works fine, but i need some properties of listview , and i have read that list<> is more efficient to populate a listview in this case, i have try with this code:

```
      List<string> mclist = new List<string>();
      listview.Items.Clear();
      foreach(string elem in mclist)
      {
      listview.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(elem));
      }
```

but how i can not make this

```
      list<string> nmfiles = new List<string>();
      nmfiles =  Directory.GetFiles(pastae).ToArray();
```

Thanks by any orientation.

Comment: you need to call the Extension method .ToXXX() the same as your starting type which is List<string> so .ToList(); is what you want to declare `nmfiles =  Directory.GetFiles(pastae).ToList(); if you had a List<T> and wanted to convert it or load it to a string[] you call .ToArray() Method

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign `string[]` to `List<string>`. However you can use `ToList()` method to convert array into list:

```
List<string> nmfiles =  Directory.GetFiles(pastae).ToList();
```